# Invalidate JWT token on logout without blacklisting

Tags: authentication, jwt, distributed-system

I was trying to build an Auth mechanism for a Distributed System. Now I want to replace traditional cookie-session based Auth( storing data in key value pair store) with JWT tokens so that I don't need a Distributed key value pair store but now the problem is invalidating this token for logout. I don't want to store any session info sticky session solution.

1. I thought of changing the secret each time but it'll log out all the user sessions. I just want to invalidate particular session only.
2. Another approach I thought of black listing tokens and storing invalid tokens in Redis with a Time to Leave value until the remaining expiry of  that JWT token but it's looping me to the same problem of using key-value storage. Although it'll require less storage than session based approach.

Is it possible without introducing a data store ? What are your thoughts on this ?

Comment: That is one of the dowsides of JWT.